# macOS Catalina v.10.15.5 Insufficient storage problem

Tags: macos, hard-drive, catalina, disk-utility, storage

I have a MacBook Pro 2017, 15". I recently performed a clean install (via USB) of the latest OS X at the time and then I've updated whenever an OS X update was available. Currently I am on v.10.15.5. The last month I started receiving alerts for insufficient storage. I have a 256Gb SSD and I'm using about 80Gb. On Disk Utility I see a strange volume which seems like inactive. Whenever I restart my machine it reports about 200Mb available and as I'm using my machine it drops slowly to about 30Mb available, which makes my machine unusable. I've tried the First Aid of Disk Utility without any results. Time Machine is not enabled by the way. I've also tried various disk management apps which do realise that I'm running out of space but only see my files (the ones included on the 80Gb).

Anyone knows how I might solve that? I'm attaching some screenshots for more information.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]